# Diophantine Equation or Ellipse

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I guess this is something to do with circle

The question is:

"Given x and y are real numbers, such that $2x^2 + 3y^2 - 4x - 12y = -14$, find xy."

What is the trick ?

Comment: Can you write the expression as $2 (x-1)^2 + 3 (y-2)^2 = 0$   then x=1 and y = 2. It has nothing to do with circle or ellipse ,   but just sum of squares is zero means each part is zero

Comment: How silly of me, didn't realise the perfect sqaure identity, Thank!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** One useful trick is completing the square. We have $2x^2-4x=2(x-1)^2-2$ and $3y^2-12y=3(y-2)^2-12$.

**Remark:** "Trick" is not really a suitable name for such a widely useful idea, which comes up in many branches of mathematics.

Comment: How silly of me, didn't realise the perfect sqaure identity, Thank!

Comment: You are welcome. Here it quickly tells us everything.  A pretty degenerate ellipse!  In other related problems, it would give us a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite

$$2x^2-4x+3y^2-12y=-14$$
$$2(x^2-2x)+3(y^2-4y)=-14$$
$$2(x^2-2x+1-1)+3(y^2-4y+4-4)=-14$$
$$2(x^2-2x+1)-2+3(y^2-4y+4)-12=-14$$
$$2(x-1)^2+3(y-2)^2-14=-14$$
$$2(x-1)^2+3(y-2)^2=0$$

When is a sum of two squares equal to zero? Only if both squares are equal to zero. So one can conclude $x-1=0$ and $y-2=0$.

Comment: How silly of me, didn't realise the perfect sqaure identity, Thank!